# How to calculate the unique amount of size pairs for a given range of width and height?

Tags: math

In my program, I generate unique pairs of WidthxHeight, e.g. 20x25.
Lets say i have a Range Height from 20 to 40, and a Range Width of 10 to 50.

In my scenario, there shouldn't be doubled pairs, e.g. if there 20x25, there sould be no 25x20 as it would be kind of the same.

I already have a working implementation where these are generated properly in a loop.

Now what I'm looking for is the math to calculate the amount of combinations beforehand to display it, without going thorugh the whole loop.

I believe there must be a quick calculation I could use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(This question is borderline at being a programming problem. I will give a brief answer here, but the question could also be asked at the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site after you add some of your own work. I'll keep my answer a little vague and leave the coding to you.)*

First decide how many pairs overall you would get. In your case there are `40-20+1 = 21` heights and `50-10+1 = 41` widths, so there are `21*41 = 861` pairs total.

Now you need to subtract the number of duplicates. First find the range of numbers that could be both heights and widths. In your case that is `20` to `40`, which is `40-20+1 = 21` numbers. A "duplicate" pair here would have two different numbers in the pair, which the larger one first. (We'll consider the case when the larger one last to be the "original".) The number of pairs of distinct numbers taken from `21` choices where the first is larger than the second is a famous combinatorial problem, with multiple ways to find the formula. I'll here just say that the answer is combinations `2` from `21`, or `21*20/2 = 210` pairs.

So your total of undouble pairs is `861-210 = 651`.

I checked this particular case with the Python expression

```
len(set([tuple(sorted((h,w))) for h in range(20,41) for w in range(10,51)]))
```

and got the expected result, `651`.

Can you turn that into a short calculation for the general case?

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
Actually I'm implementing this in Java, and this part was for the frontend to give a preview for the output, and I wanted to avoid a loop here, as the user could dynamically change these height/width values and I wanted to keep the cpu usage low.
Therefore I thought there could be an easier mathematical calculation to solve this.

Comment: @JanusReith: I do not understand your comment. My algorithm uses no loop, uses simple calculations, and would be very fast. (My check did use loops.) You would need a few `if` statements to find the overlapping range of the heights and widths but that would be fast. If this answer did help you, please accept it by clicking the checkbox at the upper left of the answer. That also helps others to see that your question was answered. I don't know Java so I can't show you any Java code.

Comment: Thank you, marked the answer as accepted.
I just tried to explain my scenario regarding the loop.
I'll try to understand your explanation how to do the calculation and implement it.

What I did'nt get yet is, where the `20` in `21*20/2` comes from.

Comment: And sorry - just realized that there is a separate math-related stackexchange.

Comment: @JanusReith: If there are `n` numbers in the overlap of heights and weights, the number of duplicates is `n * (n-1) / 2`. One way to get this is to do the summation `0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (n-1)`.

Comment: Thank you, now I understood properly how to solve this using combinations, and tested it succesfully!